# Flutter: iOS testing on Real Device does not work but just white screen

Tags: ios, flutter

I am trying to run the app on my real device. It used to work but then now, I have

```
2020-12-26 23:06:16.907475+0900 Runner[4072:1164380] <Warning>: Please set a value for FacebookAutoLogAppEventsEnabled. Set the flag to TRUE if you want to collect app install, app launch and in-app purchase events automatically. To request user consent before collecting data, set the flag value to FALSE, then change to TRUE once user consent is received. Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios#disable-auto-events.
2020-12-26 23:06:16.907988+0900 Runner[4072:1164380] <Warning>: You haven't set a value for FacebookAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled. Set the flag to TRUE if you want to collect Advertiser ID for better advertising and analytics results. To request user consent before collecting data, set the flag value to FALSE, then change to TRUE once user consent is received. Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios#disable-auto-events.
2020-12-26 23:06:17.321827+0900 Runner[4072:1164380] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
2020-12-26 23:06:17.322129+0900 Runner[4072:1164380] Metal API Validation Enabled
2020-12-26 23:06:17.496370+0900 Runner[4072:1164380] FBSDKLog: Unable to obtain a key window, marking <UIWindow: 0x108853370; frame = (0 0; 375 812); hidden = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x2824c0ba0>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x282a1dd60>> as keyWindow
2020-12-26 23:06:17.717583+0900 Runner[4072:1164625] flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:49340/oBpPo-aZas0=/
2020-12-26 23:06:18.294210+0900 Runner[4072:1164608] [Client] Updating selectors after delegate removal failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 92 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated from this process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 92 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated from this process.}
2020-12-26 23:06:18.300527+0900 Runner[4072:1164609] [tcp] tcp_input [C2.1:3] flags=[R] seq=883740456, ack=0, win=0 state=CLOSED rcv_nxt=883740456, snd_una=4000769170
2020-12-26 23:06:18.305294+0900 Runner[4072:1164609] [tcp] tcp_input [C2.1:3] flags=[R] seq=883740456, ack=0, win=0 state=CLOSED rcv_nxt=883740456, snd_una=4000769170
2020-12-26 23:06:18.305448+0900 Runner[4072:1164609] [tcp] tcp_input [C2.1:3] flags=[R] seq=883740456, ack=0, win=0 state=CLOSED rcv_nxt=883740456, snd_una=4000769170
2020-12-26 23:06:18.323253+0900 Runner[4072:1164380] FBSDKLog: starting with Graph API v2.4, GET requests for /2801278236811751/model_asset should contain an explicit "fields" parameter
2020-12-26 23:06:18.329438+0900 Runner[4072:1164596] [tcp] tcp_input [C1.1:3] flags=[R] seq=3880368660, ack=0, win=0 state=CLOSED rcv_nxt=3880368660, snd_una=3336524019
2020-12-26 23:06:18.329608+0900 Runner[4072:1164596] [tcp] tcp_input [C1.1:3] flags=[R] seq=3880368660, ack=0, win=0 state=CLOSED rcv_nxt=3880368660, snd_una=3336524019
2020-12-26 23:06:18.528960+0900 Runner[4072:1164609] [tcp] tcp_input [C4.1:3] flags=[R] seq=4057472013, ack=0, win=0 state=CLOSED rcv_nxt=4057472013, snd_una=3065118857
2020-12-26 23:06:18.529027+0900 Runner[4072:1164609] [tcp] tcp_input [C4.1:3] flags=[R] seq=4057472013, ack=0, win=0 state=CLOSED rcv_nxt=4057472013, snd_una=3065118857
2020-12-26 23:06:18.615382+0900 Runner[4072:1164608] [tcp] tcp_input [C3.1:3] flags=[R] seq=2547416679, ack=0, win=0 state=CLOSED rcv_nxt=2547416679, snd_una=2190598588
2020-12-26 23:06:18.615488+0900 Runner[4072:1164608] [tcp] tcp_input [C3.1:3] flags=[R] seq=2547416679, ack=0, win=0 state=CLOSED rcv_nxt=2547416679, snd_una=2190598588
```

this errors and my iPhone has a white screen now. Tried `hot reload` and `hot restart`. Reinstalling the app and flutter clean. I also looked up for the solution for `com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc`, but this is not working. However, the app runs totally fine on the iOS simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to run your app directly from Xcode. That won't work and will result in a white screen.

You should run your app on a real device the same way you run it on a simulator:

1. Connect your device
2. Open your project in VS Code
3. Select your device in lower right corner
4. Run your app

You can also run your app from Terminal:

1. `cd` into projects directory
2. Run `flutter run` or `flutter run --release`

Comment: I did that on terminal. I got the white screen. And, that was why I went on XCode to check the error :/